# Position of an icon on a polyline

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-polyline

*Context:* I am animating an icon along a polyline, which represents a car going from point A to B. At some point in time the car is low on fuel, hence, i need to go to a gas station and afterwards continue to point B.

Hence, when the car is low on fuel, i *compute* the car's *current position* and make a directions request from the current position to point B, with the gas station as a waypoint.

Once i've got the answer, i update the polyline on which the car is animated (i retain accomplished parts and replace the remaining parts by the new route).

---

The problem is that the computed "current position" of the car is way too inaccurate (i.e. **the computed position differs from the actual position of the icon** on the polyline).

Here is a minimal working example and its [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0wozuvs5/):

```
var map;
var line;
var first_path;

function initMap() {
    pointA = new google.maps.LatLng(50.931300, 4.226360);
    pointB = new google.maps.LatLng(48.858370, 2.294481);

    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 7,
        center: pointA
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), myOptions);

    // Instantiate a directions service.
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService,
        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
            map: map
        }),
        markerA = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: pointA,
            title: "point A",
            label: "A",
            map: map
        }),
        markerB = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: pointB,
            title: "point B",
            label: "B",
            map: map
        });

    // get route from A to B
    calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay, pointA, pointB);
}



function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay, pointA, pointB) {
    directionsService.route({
        origin: pointA,
        destination: pointB,
        avoidTolls: true,
        avoidHighways: false,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    }, function (response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            //directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);

            console.debug(response);
            first_path = response.routes[0].overview_path;

            // Make polyline on the path
            line = new google.maps.Polyline({
                path: first_path,
                strokeColor: 'black',
                strokeOpacity: 1,
                icons: [{
                    icon: {
                        path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
                        scale: 5,
                        strokeColor: '#393',
                        strokeOpacity: 0.8
                    },
                    offset: '90%'
                }]
            });

            line.setMap(map);

            // Add a marker at the same position as the icon --> INACCURATE
            var loc = line.GetPointAtDistance(line.Distance() * 0.9);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                      position: loc,
                      map: map,
                      title: 'Wrong position!'
                    });

        } else {
            window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
        }
    });
}

initMap();
```

Please note that i am using the Epoly V3 library for this computation.

Are there any other libraries or ways to compute the current position which might work?

Comment: I see what you are asking about.  The issue is (probably, will take some investigation) the difference in the way the 90% is calculated for the icon position vs. the position calculated by the GetPointAtDistance routine, but it isn't obvious (particularly since the icon position calculated by the API isn't available).

Comment: @geocodezip Probably, indeed. Any pointers on how to investigate this? I have no geographical background, which is why i used the Epoly library in the first place.

Comment: I have been looking at it.  As far as I can tell epoly is doing the correct thing.  I replaced the relevant calls with calls to the geometry library in the API, and it gets the same result (or at least within centimeters), which leads me to suspect the API is putting the icon at the wrong place, but can't prove it as the details of that position aren't available. A work around would be to use epoly to display the icon on the polyline.  At this point I see the difference, but don't understand how that is affecting your code/application.

Comment: @geocodezip I will give that a try, but i'm not sure i fully understand what you mean by using epoly to display the icon. Do you mean using epoly to compute the position of the car, and then display the car icon at that position (using a marker rather than an icon since an icon requires an offset, right?). Concretely, my application simulates a car, speed limits, etc. Since the car isn't displayed where he really is, the car sometimes seems to drive too fast/slow based on its displayed position (which is wrong, the car is right...)

Comment: @geocodezip You were right, thanks a lot! I now display the car as a marker and move it using the positions computed with the epoly library. However, it seems quite expensive to compute the location using `GetPointAtDistance` many times per second. I guess there is no workaround though.